# Interrupt batch job between files

Tags: bash, batch

I need to setup my bash batch job (compressing 5.1k files inplace) so that if I need to stop / resume the job it will wait until it is "between" files (has just finished one and hasn't started another).

My compression would look like `pigz -9 -- rsnc*` if all run at once, and I was contemplating something like:

```
ls rsnc* | while read file 
  do pigz -9 -- $file
  if [ -f .intr ]
    then break
  fi
done
```

Is this a reliable means of achieving my goal? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you have only to suspend it you can use `Ctrl-Z`. It will answer with the number of the job (for example [3]) in the job list. Then you can resume it with `%3`.

Comment: No I need to stop it, because I would need to disconnect an external drive in the case where I needed to stop the batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `trap` <sup>[[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)],[[2](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash)]</sup>  the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal, the INT one, and `wait` for the ending of each process.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        wait   # wait for the end of all child processes    
        exit   # <<--- put here your exit code exit 1, ... 
}

shopt -s nullglob
for f in rsnc*
do
    pigz -9 -- $file &   # Execute in background
    wait  $!             # Wait for the end of the last command 
done
```

**Note**
There are many ways to cycle over all the files in a directory <sup>[[3](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/)]</sup>, but it's always **better to avoid to parse the output of `ls`** <sup>[[4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388)]</sup>.

**References**

- [Trapping ctrl-c in Bash](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash), a simple example.
- [Traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) from the Bash Guide for Beginners - Chapt 12.
- [Bash loop over files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/).
- Some reasons why it is better to [avoid to parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the hazards of parsing `ls`, though in this case the filenames are all known-safe. I wonder, why background the `pigz` then wait on it? wouldn't running pigz in the foreground achieve the same thing? Also `$!` is generally the last argument to the previous command, does it mean something else here?

Comment: You're welcome. :) 1. It's always possible that there is  a file that you didn't checked, or that in a far far tomorrow  you will reuse on other files (and you forget about it). 2. In background because else you will interrupt in the middle `pigz`  3.Nope `$!` returns the PID of the last command executed in background (`&`).

Comment: Here `wait $!`  do the same of the simple `wait`. Of course it will be different if you want to run _n_ parallel time `pigz` on different files and wait until the number of child process will be less then that _n_. (You will not need any more that `wait $!` but another cycle and with a test and a sleep...). This will hold  if you want to run a bunch of `pigz` in parallel and wait for the last. ps> you can trap other signal if you prefer...

Comment: Oops, I was thinking `!$`. Yeah I can't run `pigz` in parallel, as it already uses all my cores on individual files (it sure is fast though); but that's not a problem with your answer just some info. I thought that since the `INT` handler calls `wait`, that having `pigz` in the foreground would still be waited on, and not passed the `INT`? Not trying to imply you're wrong just that more clarification of control flow would be welcome.

Comment: If I understand well the output of `help wait` when it says _If ID is not given, waits for __all currently active child processes__, and the return status..._ it seems to suggest that if it not in background `&`, or in a subshell `()`,  it is not a __child__ one and we shouldn't expect that `wait` will wait for it. You can test (it is interesting). ps> You can trap even other signal if you want... and from system to system it can vary the name of the signal (usually `kill -l` for a list).